# Testing Firebase auth method 'Google Sign In With Popup' - Jest

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, testing, jestjs

I am trying to figure out how to mock the google sign in popup method using jest.
Here is the auth file

```
import { firebase, googleProvider } from "./firebase";
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);

  function startLogin() {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
  }

  function logOut() {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()

      .then(() => {
        setUser(null);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      }

      setIsAuthenticating(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [currentUser]);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    isAuthenticating,

    startLogin,
    logOut,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!isAuthenticating && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The login method is called through the login component

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../auth/auth";
import { history } from "../routes/AppRouter";
import logo192 from "../images/logo192.png";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { useStyles } from "../styles/LoginStyle";

export const Login = () => {
  const { startLogin } = useAuth();

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      await startLogin();

      history.push("/welcome");
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box className={classes.loginDiv}>
      <img src={logo192} alt="react-logo" className={classes.reactLogo} />

      <Box className={classes.welcomeText}>
        <Typography variant="h3">React Quiz App</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5">
          Take 10 random questions and find out how smart you are
        </Typography>
      </Box>
      <Button
        data-testid="login-button"
        className={classes.login}
        onClick={login}
      >
        LOGIN
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Now I want to test (mock the method I think) using jest so something like the below
Not sure if i should test by importing the login component or the auth.js file?

```
describe("firebase auth methods", () => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{}}>
      <Login />
    </AuthContext.Provider>,
    container
  );


  it("should call google sign in with popup", () => {
    ///call the sign in with pop method here
  });

});
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated :D